# OData String Maxvalue, how long can it be?

Tags: string, metadata, odata

I´m getting the following metadata from OData:

```
<Property Name="CustomerDesc" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="Max" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true"/>
```

I could not find any specification about how long: MaxLength="Max" can be.
Is there any limitation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the OData V4 [spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/csprd01/part3-csdl/odata-v4.0-csprd01-part3-csdl.html#_Toc355092848)(preview and not the current version),

> 6.2.2 Attribute MaxLength
>   A binary, stream or string property MAY define a positive integer value for the MaxLength facet attribute. The value of this attribute specifies the maximum length of the value of the property on a type instance. Instead of an integer value the constant max MAY be specified as a shorthand for the maximum length supported by the server.
>   If no value is specified, the property has unspecified length.

So, it is up to the server implementation to assign a value for max.